# Separating dual booting systems from one hard disk to different hard disks

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive, mbr

Due to my recent hardware upgrade I'm planning to separate the two dual booting operating systems that I have (Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7), onto two different hard disks from the partitions on which they currently reside on one hard disk.

I have installed the operating systems on disk on Ubuntu first, Windows second - basis thus my disk boots from the Windows partition grub showing the Ubuntu kernel entries plus a Windows loader entry like it should and everything is working fine.

Partition table:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048   218370047   109184000   83  Linux
/dev/sda3       300286980   312580095     6146558    5  Extended
/dev/sda4   *   218371545   300286979    40957717+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       300287043   312580095     6146526+  82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Now, I'm planning to completely move Ubuntu onto a new disk, leaving Windows completely occupying the old disk.Of course, the first part should be easy, cloning the Ubuntu installation to another (bigger :) ) disk - bootable. But, to be on the safe side I'd rather listen to any and all advices, suggestions, notes etc. on how to really proceed with the old disk.

Yes, delete the other 3 partitions and occupy the whole space with Windows partition should sound sane. Then I'd suspect if I'm using the newer disk as a primary disk that I should use Windows disk to install Windows MBR on the old disk and after that use [Boot Repair Disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) to update the grub loader on the newer disk to gain entry to Windows, right? I do know how to use them both, and have used them many times, never in this manner though. But maybe I am completely going wrong in this section?

Are there some other things I need to take into consideration prior to deleting the other partitions or even doing anything at all? Not feeling confident at all. Thank you very much in advance!